# Move point onto circle-outline in R3

Tags: geometry, circles, 3d

I need to do all this in $\mathbb{R}^3$

- a plane by $n \cdot p = -k$
- a circle within this plane by radius = $r$ and center = $c$
- a point $a$ on the inside on the circle (on the plane)
- a direction $d$ orthogonal to $n$

Now I want to move $a$ onto the circle outline using $d$. I am not sure how to find the scalar $s$ needed to "hit" the outline of the circle
with $o = a + sd$ where $o$ is the point on the outline.

I was thinking of the cosine law but then I don't know the wanted point on the circle outline.

Can someone help me? A closed form solution would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\theta$ be the angle between $a-c$ and $d$. Then by the law of cosines applied to triangle $aoc$ you get:
$$
s^2+2sl\cos\theta+l^2-r^2=0,
$$
where $l$ is the distance between $a$ and $c$. From that you can readily compute $s$:
$$
s=\sqrt{r^2-l^2\sin^2\theta}-l\cos\theta.
$$

Comment: yes I can follow that myself now. Somehow I missed that I can use the $d$ for the angle. Thanks!

Comment: although there is a sign mistake: I think it should be $s = \sqrt{ ... } + l \cos \theta$

Comment: It depends on which angle you choose as $\theta$ between the two formed by $d$ with line $ac$.

Comment: ah of course! Thanks again